# I want to get part of the url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
http://localhost:6223/RssFeed/RssFeedsLang?lang=Dari&cat=News
```

How can I get the `http://localhost:6223/` of the url? Basically I want to discard `/RssFeed/RssFeedsLang?lang=Dari&cat=News` in the url. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
string urlBase = Request.Url.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Authority ) + Request.ApplicationPath;
```